# Fix horizontal spacing between characters

Tags: inkscape, spacing

I have a SVG file. It was opened in Inkscape from a PDF file, if that matters. The SVG contains left aligned text which I need to make right aligned.

Easy enough, I use the text tool, click onto the text and make it right aligned. But then, this happens:

[image: Horizontal alignment broken]

The characters of the word "Outlook" and "Meeting" overlap. It looks a bit like kerning is broken.

Each text is one text element only and it does not have additional spaces. But, I notice a diamond when being in text edit mode:

[image: Diamond]

What can I do to fix that?

I have tried:

- re-writing all text. This works, but I don't want to do that, since I could introduce typos or similar.

This is Inkscape 1.0.2-2 from 2021-01-15

Comment: Are the words connected? In other words, are they 1 string of text or multiple small strings of a character or two? PDFs can break text objects apart. In Ai you can do [**this**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22065/opening-pdf-in-illustrator-breaks-up-text-objects) but I don't know if that works in Inkscape.

Comment: @Scott: thanks for asking. It's one text element only. But I noticed a diamond, which IMHO wasn't there before when the text was left aligned. Updated the question.

Comment: Related: [similar issue for vertical spacing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105537/fix-vertical-spacing-or-reset-default-text-style)

Comment: "opened in Inkscape from a PDF file, if that matters." Yes it probably does matter. That can often result in messed up text if you try to edit it. I would delete the text entirely, and just retype it as an Inkscape text object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the text block once to select, then click on the Text menu and select 'Remove Manual Kerns'.

Text can get really screwed up from PDFs but I've found the above often fixes things.

Comment: That's much better than my approach, because it can be applied to several selected texts at once.

Answer (score 1):

With the Node tool (<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>) you can move the diamond more to the left. Once the diamond is further left than the text length, the text looks normal.

[image: Node edit tool]